# GDB stuck at “Configuring GDB Aborting configuring GDB”

Tags: c, arm, gdb, embedded, eclipse-cdt

I've installed (OSX Mojave 10.14.6.) Eclipse CDT and [GNU MCU Eclipse plugin](https://gnu-mcu-eclipse.github.io/) and finaly [GNU Tools for ARM](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/open-source-software/developer-tools/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm). My goal is to build and debug ARM code using GDB (`arm-none-eabi-gdb`).

I've created a Hello World project for Arm, which builds ok - but, debugging seems not to work with GDB (that comes with the Arm package). GDB gets stuck:
[image: Configuring GDB Aborting configuring GDB.]

I have set the proper paths in Eclipse to `arm-none-eabi-gdb`.
I have signed the `arm-none-eabi-gdb` (with the same certificate that I used to sign GDB installed via `brew` into `/usr/local/bin/gdb` the day before - and it worked!).
I have also tried running Eclipse as `root` from command line.

Nothing helps.
The message is "Configuring GDB Aborting configuring GDB".

What to do?

Comment: Are you running in a simulator or on a physical ARM processor? In case of the latter, what in-circuit debugger are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what is going on here is that you built to a given target (ARM based) and you're trying to run it (with gdb) on your mac (x86).

You'll need an emulator or QEMU to properly run on your mac or maybe a real board.

Comment: Yes, I was missing QEMU, all good now, thanks. Strange that session hangs like this without any warning message.